# Additional References

Tags: discussion

Stack Overflow and SE sites have a very specific model that requests very specific questions and very specific answers. That's just the nature of the beast.

I see a lot of questions that have a long-list of "references and additional reading." These are usually broad topics that do not address the question directly, if at all.

I don't think that irrelevant material should be included in answers. But, how should we deal with this kind of content?

Answer (score 3):

Because of the nature of our topic, we can't give up giving references. I think most we can do is to embed them inside answer [like this](http://www.example.com), rather than making a list at the end of answer.

As for additional reading, a religious topic might not be as clear cut as programming. I mean, for some questions, even though your answer may summarize subject, additional reading might be required for details. I think we could make judgement per answer, because, I don't think banning it altogether would be constructive.

Comment: I think you missed my point entirely. I'm not calling for a lack of sources; I'm calling for *embedding them within your answer* instead of listing a large number of long sources at the end and leaving people to figure out what parts of your email are quoted/sourced and what parts are you.

Comment: @ashes999 Sorry, I misunderstood. In that case, I agree with you.